# Retrieve first value in a row and put in a cosecutive columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df that looks like this:

```
   A    B   C   D    E   F
1  20   0   0   60   0   0
2  50   0   0   150  50  0 
3  30   0   0   120  0   0
4  40   0   0   60   0   0 
5  30   100 0   160  0   0
```

I want to extract first value from columns B:F and modulo this value by the value from column A. If the modulo of the row is not equal to 0 (like in the case of row 4), I want to skip it. If it's not, I want to sum up values from columns B:F and divide it by the value of column A and get the floor number. So in the first row it would be 3. Then put number from column A into three consecutive columns starting from D. So it'd look like this:

```
     A   B   C   D    E    F
  1  20  0   0   20   20   20
```

In case of row 2, I want it to look like this and also create another df that would start from column G and put the rest of values there.

```
df1
   A    B   C   D    E   F
2  50   0   0   50  50  50 


df2
       G
    2  50
```

I've done the first part, however I got stuck after that with indexing and putting the values in consecutive columns

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import math


for i in df.iloc[:, -6:].values:
    x = i[i>0][0]  # value of column A
    y = i[i>0][1]  # first value
    if y%x != 0:
        continue
    else:
        z = sum(i[1:])
```

Thank you for any input, I'll gladly accept any help and advice.

**EDIT**

Final dfs should look like this:

```
df1
   A    B   C   D    E   F
1  20   0   0   20   20  20
2  50   0   0   50   50  50 
3  30   0   0   30   30  30
4  40   0   0   60   0   0 
5  30   100 0   160  0   0

df2
       G
    2  50 
    3  30
```

Comment: I don't know if I understand what you mean by "the modulo of the row". Are you looking for rows in which *each other* value is *divisible by* the value from the first column?

Comment: Yes. I didn't know how to explain it - so in case of first row I would put value of 20 in three rows starting from D (60%20 = 3), in second row it would be in four columns starting from D (200%50 = 4) and so on, and so on

Comment: In the case of the second row, where does the 200 come from? And what *problem do you solve* by doing all of this - what do the numbers represent, anyway?

Comment: 200 is a sum of rows of values from columns B:F - so 150 + 50.
Column A is a monthly subscription fee, next columns are months - in case of row 1, somebody paid 60 in month D with subscription fee of 20 monthly. So he paid for 3 months and that's how it should show up

Comment: And what would you do if the sum was instead 250?

Comment: I'd need another df, since column F is December in my dataset. So df1 is dataset for 2020 in which column F represents December. If the number of months that the subscription is paid for is bigger than the number of months left in this year I need to create another df which represent year 2021

Comment: Is possible see how looks finally both DataFrames?

Comment: Added final dfs